# SQLHeavy for MySQL/PostgreSQL - where to start

Tags: mysql, vala

I've seen the usage docs for SQLHeavy (I've been itching for something similar for quite some time) and it's a very cool abstraction layer.

I want the same functionality for MySQL/PostgreSQL.

- Has the code behind SQLHeavy been created with plug-able database drivers in mind or is it 100% dedicated to SQLite?
- If plug-ability was not taken into account, knowing the code base how clean would it be for me to attempt a port? To clarify would it need serious structure/logic changes in the code or just identify an replace every SQLite specific function and change to MySQL specific function and adapt/process arguments?

Note: I'm a PHP dev (with some C/C++/Java background) planning to work pet projects (not necessarily low involvement) in Vala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's dedicated to SQLite, and porting it isn't really feasible.

When I created SQLHeavy I (very) briefly considered supporting multiple databases, but lots of functionality simply doesn't translate well to other databases and SQLHeavy was really designed to make accessing SQLite databases easier, not to abstract away differences between databases.

You might want to take a look at libgda, which is a very impressive project.  They distribute Vala bindings, and support multiple databases (including Postgres and MySQL).

Comment: I knew it was specifically intended for SQLite and expected to see a lot of SQLite specific syntax but workarounds for SQL syntax are OK - usually MySQL/PostgreSQL will have more features rather than less in comparison to SQLite. But are there work flow "features" - in my case roadblocks - that will need a complete rewrite?

Comment: SQLite has lots of features that other databases don't.  The SQL dialect tends to be a bit more limited, but other things are vastly more flexible.  In SQLite custom functions are created per-connection and written in native code.  AFAIK, in MySQL they are per-database and written in SQL and PostgreSQL are per-database and in PL/SQL.  I think SQLite is also the only one with the concept of implicit ROWID columns (which SQLHeavy uses heavily).  I'm also not aware of an easy way to handle change notification.

Comment: Implicit `ROWID` columns are present in PostgresQL as `OID`. MySQL has a `_rowid` column present if the table has a PK or other UNIQUE key defined using just one numeric column.

Comment: PostgreSQL (now) has PL/SQL or many other languages such as PL/Java, PL/Perl, PL/php, PL/Python, PL/R, PL/Ruby, PL/sh, PL/Tcl, and PL/Lua. The functions are indeed stored at the database level and executed by a separate process (not the current running application thread) which means current context does not exist.

Comment: So, long story short, you could have /similar/ APIs, but a /compatible/ API is a much more difficult (likely impossible) proposition, at least without crippling SQLHeavy.

Comment: Yeah, most abstraction libraries present the lowest common denominator of features from all of the supported engines. Hence the crippling.